# Esp32 cam board not capturing image,showing in the serial monitor 0+0+0+0=0 0”

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am using esp32 cam board , I have downloaded board and all things. I am using the library example code "cameraWebServer". But when I start streaming, in serial monitor it is showing ......... , "0+0+0+0=0 0"

In webpage it is just showing thumbnail, not video . Please help...

Answer (score 0):

We lack a lot of information here, so I just try because I had problems with setting up a cam myself recently.
First of all did you follow a good tutorial? I would look for https://randomnerdtutorials.com/projects-esp32-cam/

If that not help, did you change the code in any way and mind posting your changes if you did?